# Error publishing web service in IIS - Could not find a base... binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https]

Tags: web-services, wcf, web-config

I'm trying to publish a webservice created and published in VS2015. When I publish it in IIS, I have the following error:
**Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https]**
I saw a lot of posts about it, and I tried to change my IIS and my web.config with no success.

I have configured a https website in IIS with self-signed certificate. It works normally, but when I try to access the webservice, I got the error that I described above. If I use this webservice in http websites, it works with no problem.

My web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.6" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>  
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <!--CONFIGURAÇÃO DO SERVIÇO-->
    <services>      
      <service name="ServicoRest.ServiceGestorWMS">
        <endpoint address="../ServiceGestorWMS.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ServicoRest.IServiceGestorWMS" behaviorConfiguration="webBehaviour" />
        <endpoint address="mex"  
                  binding="mexHttpsBinding"  
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />  
      </service>
    </services>
     <bindings>
   <webHttpBinding>
    <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="webHttpsBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
 </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <!--CONFIGURAÇÃO DO SERVIÇO-->
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehaviour">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <!--SE VOCÊ PRECISAR ACESSAR O SERVIÇO DE OUTRO DOMÍNIO VIA JAVASCRIPT VOCÊ DEVE INFORMAR O BLOCO DE CÓDIGO ABAIXO -->
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=;initial catalog=;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: {D84BF523-87CA-4D7D-90AE-CEE789984582}-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Murphy,

You do not seem to have set the binding. You would need something like the code below in your web.config if you want to support HTTP and HTTPS for the webHttpBinding:

```
<webHttpBinding>
    <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="webHttpsBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Hello Wallis. Thanks for your time here. I have tried to add your chunck of code, but it not works. See the web.config now (I have edited with your code).